# Detect if monitor is rotated

Tags: java, swing, multiple-monitors

I have an application in JavaSE and i want my application always starts at center of screen. If two monitors are plugged, the right one should be used. So i wrote a code like this:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
if(ge.getScreenDevices().length == 2) {
    int w_1 = ge.getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int h_1 = ge.getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    int w_2 = ge.getScreenDevices()[1].getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int h_2 = ge.getScreenDevices()[1].getDisplayMode().getHeight();


    int x = w_1 + w_2  / 2 - getWidth() / 2;
    int y = h_2 / 2 - getHeight() / 2;

    setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Unfortunately if monitor is rotated at 90°, width and height should be flipped. Is there any way to detect such rotation?

Comment: If the monitor is flipped, wouldn't the user want to setup the system to have width and height flipped? I mean... if they didn't configure it the display would be sideways, wouldn't it?

Comment: no...i just tested it, if one of monitors is rotated the position is not center of screen.

Comment: Try using [setLocationRelativeTo(null);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29). If that doesn't work, try [GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getCenterPoint%28%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know whether the second monitor is in portrait mode.  Just find the bounds of the screen in device coordinates and use the center.  (If it is in portrait mode, then height>width, but that isn't an important piece of information.)

Your formula to determine the center point of the second device is wrong.  You are assuming that the coordinates of the second screen runs from (w_1,0) to (w_1 + w_2, h_2), but that isn't necessarily true.  You need to find the GraphicsConfiguration object of the second screen and call [GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getBounds%28%29) on it.  You can then calculate the center point of that rectangle.

If you want to know which device is on the left or the right (or top or bottom), you can compare the x (or y) values of their bounding rectangles.  Note that the x or y values may be negative.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider if the height is bigger than the width(portrait). I haven't heard anyone using portrait monitors yet, though.

Comment: used to use a 3 monitor setup where i had the 3rd monitor as a portrait for reading documentation, worked awesomely

Comment: I've seen a couple developers use it so they can get more code on the screen at once, not my cup o' tea though.

Comment: @user1454653: You just have! I use two portrait monitors at work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works fine in most cases (from answer of Enwired).

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
if(ge.getScreenDevices().length == 2) {
    int x = (int)ge.getScreenDevices()[1].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getCenterX() - frame.getWidth() / 2;
    int y = (int)ge.getScreenDevices()[1].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getCenterY() - frame.getHeight() / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
}
```

The only problem is that device index is not always 0 - left, 1 - right.